# Listings to show up in all states and having it set to one or nothing

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, smarty

I am working with an online classified site that has partnered with online retailers that sell through out the US and not in one particular state. How can I set the "listings" for each product such as a surfboard, skateboard etc to show up in search results for every state if that is what a user wants to search by?

Here's the problem... If "Company A" sends me a spreadsheet of their Surfboard inventory to upload, and they sell nationwide, I can just leave the "State" field blank so that it will appear in universal search results (search all). However, if somebody was to search Surfboards by "State", "Company A's" listings will not show up. I am trying to find a way to have "Company A's" listings appear in all States. I don't want to have to upload their inventory per State since that's just insane. Is there any solution to this? There's a lot of "used" listings that are posted by Users and are location based but when it comes to these companies that want there listings to show in every State, i am not sure how to approach that..or if its even possible.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some code if possible, and in any case please explain in greater detail what problem you are trying to solve and what difficulties you have encountered. As it stands, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to write a useful answer to this question.

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully it helps..

Comment: How are you storing these things? Some sort of database? Which? How are you performing queries? Details. Show the code.